# Groovy - How to see java method System.out.println

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have written a `groovy scripts` in `SOAP UI` that calls a method from a java class -`MyClass`  , placed inside the jar.It is doing the job properly but none of the `System.out.println` present in the method -`invokeProcess` shows in the SOAP UI log output .
How can I get that?

Example 
`foo.jar` is in the lib for SOAP.

**Groovy Script**

```
import foo.*;
foo.MyClass.invokeProcess(strValue)
```

**Java Class inside foo.jar**

```
public class MyClass{

  public static void invokeProcess(String strValue){
   //do something
   System.out.println("show abcd");
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you know where the standard output is going? Normally server-based applications use a logger exactly for this reason.

Comment: @chrylis I get your point that I should use logger , but is there any way I can get the sysouts? this is an existing old class where I cant make any changes

Comment: They're going to the stdout of your server process. Find out where that is.

Comment: @chrylis how can I find that? I am running soap ui groovy script

Comment: @2manFace, can you check the solution to see if that helps?

Comment: @2FaceMan, have you got chance to try the solution? Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them with small change to your method. Just pass an additional arameter `log` and use `log.info`

Just change it as(of course, need to recreate jar and place it under soapui and restart the tool):

```
public static void invokeProcess(String strValue, def log){
   //do something
   log.info("show abcd");
}
```

In the Groovy Script, call it as import foo.*;

```
foo.MyClass.invokeProcess(strValue, log)
```

In general `println` or `System.out.println` statements go into `soapui.log` file, you may find it under `SOAPUI_HOME/bin` directory or under User profile directory.

Comment: I cannot change the existing code ,so looking for workaound